# Without using differential forms, can we unify or organize all the various multivariable integrals: multiple, line, flux, etc.?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definition

In single dimension calculus, there is one and only one obvious way of integrating: over an interval.  Of course, there are multiple ways of defining the integral (Riemann sum, Darboux integral, Lebesgue integral), but, where defined, these definitions agree.

Once we move from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^n$, there seems to be a plethora of types of integrals, with most sources making no attempt to unify or organize them:

> [In this section](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/CalcIII.aspx) we will continue looking at line integrals and define the second kind of line integral we’ll be looking at... [In this section](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/CalcIII.aspx) we will define the third type of line integrals we’ll be looking at: line integrals of vector fields.

> [The Area under a Curve and its Many Generalizations](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/HTML/chapter20/contents.html)... The method of doing this used is generalized to define a *wide variety of integrals*...

Is there a way to unify or at least organize all these types of integrals?

My attempt to do so is below.  Is it correct? What revisions does it need? **Update:** My goal is to do this in a simple way, without invoking the complexity and abstraction of differential forms.

---

For $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^m$, the one obvious way to integrate is over an interval of $\mathbb R$.  When instead $f$ takes an input in $\mathbb R^n$, we gain one, and in some cases two, new ways to integrate:

### Region ("Multiple") Integrals

For multiple dimensions, with $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, we can take the integral over any "nice" $k \leq n$ dimensional *region* of $\mathbb R^n$.  We can do this for regions of any dimension $k \leq n$ by partitioning it into very small subregions.  However, for $k > 1$, these subregions are not defined by two endpoints such that we can define  $\Delta x_i$.  Rather, we need to take the *size* or [*region measure*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html) (hypervolume, volume, area, etc.) appropriate for $k$ (irrespective of $n$) of each subregion. This partition is, unlike intervals, unordered and unoriented, and the size of each subregion is always positive:
$$\sum_{r_{i, j,...} \in R}f(\xi_{i,j,...})\cdot \|r_{i,j,...}\|.$$

The integral is the limit of such as $\max_{i,j,...} \|r_{i,j,...}\| \to 0$ (provided it exists).  (And the fact that the partition unordered and unoriented, with each subregion having positive size, is the reason why the Change of Variables Theorem uses the absolute value of the determinant and not the determinant itself.)

By Fubini's theorem, this limit is (under reasonable conditions) equal to an iterated integral, and so these are often called *multiple integrals*.  However, it is important to emphasize that there is nothing "multiple" in the definition of multiple integrals: They are limits of *single* Riemann sums over partitions of regions with dimension $> 1$.

This definition therefore includes *volume integrals*, *area integrals*, *line integrals over scalar fields*; all are simply region integrals, defined the same way, with the region having different dimensions.

### Vector Field Integrals: Line (dim = 1) and Flux (codim = 1)

Furthermore, if $n = m$, then $f$ defines a *vector field*, and we gain the ability to take the dot product $f(x) \cdot x$.  This gives us two new ways to take integrals: *line integrals* and *flux integrals*.

If the region is a curve (i.e. $k = 1$), we can approximate each subregion $r_i$ by a vector $s_i \in \mathbb R^n$ and take the Riemann sum of $$\sum f(\xi_i) \cdot s_i.$$

And if the region is a surface (i.e. $k = n - 1$), we can construct a *flux integral* by approximating each $r_i$ by an $k$ dimensional hyperplane $p_i$ and letting $n_i$ be the unique vector that is normal to $p_i$, has magnitude equal to the "size" (volume, area, etc.) of $p_i$, and has a sign determined by convention, giving the Riemann sum of
$$\sum f(\xi_i) \cdot n_i.$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form

Comment: @SRobertJames You're looking for the theory of [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form). The different kinds of integration correspond to how each of the different differential forms is integrated.

Comment: @SRobertJames Incidentally, the theorems relating these integrals (Green's theorem, the fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals, Stokes' theorem, the divergence theorem) can all be understood as instances of the [generalized Stokes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem)

Comment: @SRobert That said, this doesn't seem to be totally comprehensive for your interests: line and surface integrals of scalar fields don't really fit into this framework

Comment: For region integrals: I'm not sure if all of these integrals use unoriented/unordered regions. Also, there's an important subtlety that should be noted: line integrals of scalar fields, surface integrals of scalar fields, and volume integrals all occur within 3-dimensional space but require different contextual notions of "size".

Comment: Other than that, everything seems fine so far

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you.  I added a note about the "size" measure's dependence on $k$.  Re orientation: Can you give an example of $k > 1$ where there is an orientation or order? To me this would seem impossible.

Comment: Your title seems to be asking "can this be done?", but the question body seems to be asking "what (if anything) is wrong with my attempt?". I recommend you change one to be closer to the other so your question is clear.

Comment: I hate to say this, but I think this is a misguided effort. I think a better goal should be to find a way to understand why differential forms cannot be avoided. I think what you never see are simple examples that demonstrate how differential forms arise naturally. I'm teaching a course on this during the spring, and your question makes me realize that I should think about this in more depth.

Comment: @Deane An answer showing "simple examples that demonstrate how differential forms arise naturally" would be very appropriate here.  Re "misguided effort" - I think above effectively characterizes and unifies all the types of integrals routinely found in physics, engineering, etc., in some ways better than the abstractions of differential forms.

Comment: @SRobertJames, the challenge occurs when you want to use different parameterizations for a surface or, in higher dimensions, a submanifold. It is not easy to see how to rewrite the integral appropriately. The other issue is that some things, such as the magnetic field, look like vector fields but aren't. Even the physicists know this and call them pseudovector fields. And then it becomes even more mysterious and messy to do this in, say, 4 dimensional space-time.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Regarding line and surface integrals of scalar fields, there is a closely related version of differential forms called [densities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_on_a_manifold) that provide a unifying framework. They are basically unsigned differential forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quite like [Terry Tao's comment/explanation](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/preprints/forms.pdf) that the distinct notions of 'integral'/'integration' are *really and essentially* about distinct things:

> The concept of integration is of course fundamental in single-variable calculus. Actually, there are *three* concepts of integration which appear in the subject: *the indefinite integral* $\int f$ (also known as the *anti-derivative*), the *unsigned definite integral*  $\int_{[a,b]} f(x) dx$ (which one would use to find area under a curve, or the mass of a one-dimensional object of varying density), and the *signed definite integral* $\int^b_a f(x) dx$ (which one would use for instance to compute the work required to move a particle from $a$ to $b$). [...] These three integration concepts are of course closely related to each other in singlevariable calculus; [...]
>
> When one moves from single-variable calculus to several-variable calculus, though, these three concepts begin to diverge significantly from each other. The indefinite integral generalises to the notion of a *solution to a differential equation*, or of an *integral* of a connection, vector field, or bundle. The unsigned definite integral generalises to the *Lebesgue integral*, or more generally to *integration on a measure space*. Finally, the signed definite integral generalises to the *integration of forms*, which will be our focus here. While these three concepts still have some relation to each other, they are not as interchangeable as they are in the single-variable setting.

That they coalesce so nicely in the one-dimensional case may very well be a small miracle

Comment: Interesting.  Would you agree that unsigned definite integrals correspond to the _region integrals_ I identified above (each involves partitioning the region and summing the value of the function in the subregion weighted by the size of the subregion), while the the signed definite integrals correspond to the line integral (each is moving _through_ the line, accumulating products of $step \cdot function value$)? How do flux integrals fit into to Tao's scheme?

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb R$ you integrate a function over an interval, $\mathbb R ^2$ you integrate over and area, in $\mathbb R^3$ a volume. In higher dimensions, the region of integration is often considered a generalized volume, and sometimes this generalized volume even refers to an interval or an area.

So in general, there's integration of a single valued function over some "volume" or sub-region of our space.

If we have a vector valued function integrated over a curve, we have a line integral by definition. Ultimately though this can be transformed into the usual single valued function over an interval via the dot product. There are theorems allowing a transformation of some line integrals into an area integral. For example, the magnetic flux through a surface can be found by explicitly calculating the flux, $\Phi_B = \int\int \vec{B} \cdot \hat{n} dS$ or using the Magnetic Vector Potential $\vec{A}$ where $\vec{B} = \nabla \times \vec{A}$. To wit, $\Phi_B = \int \vec{A} \cdot \vec{dl}$ where the flux is a line integral of the vector potential along the boundary of the surface in question.

Flux is an integral over a surface by definition, and a surface implies area. So the  Electric Flux is $\Phi_E=\int\int \vec{E} \cdot \hat{n} dS$. This can be converted to a volume integral so that $\Phi_E = \int\int\int \nabla \cdot \vec{E} d\tau$ .

Both the conversion from a surface integral to a line integral and a volume integral to a surface integral are manifestations of some fundamental principles from the study of differential forms. In both cases the ultimate results can be found by integrating over a boundary.

The above mentioned integrals give you a scalar result, but similar principles apply over more general Tensors. A vector is a Rang 1 tensor. A Tensor can loosely be thought of as a nested vector. For example, consider $T^{\alpha\beta}$ as a momentum flux. In the $\alpha$ direction, the $\beta$ component of momentum $\vec{p}$ is changing at rate $T^{\alpha \beta}$.

So there's a general principle in play regarding Exterior Derivatives that establishes relationships between the integral of a tensor over a generalized volume that gives you the same result as the integral of a tensor derivative over a boundary "surface".

Ultimately the general form results from multiple integrals over some region of the parameter space.